# Create a tablelayout programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Im new to xamarin and i'm trying to create a table layout in my main activity, but I dont want to create it from the xml.
I have a number, and I want to create a table based on this number. if the number can be divided by 2, I want that in each row there will be 2 colums. else, I want to create rows that in each row there will be 2 colums, and in the last row only one colum.
sorry for the poor english.
thnx!

Answer (score 1):

First, create your main layout (Main.axml) like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" />
```

Then in your MainActivity.cs do this :

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLayout); //get your linearlayout from your Main.axml
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this); //create a new tablelayout
mainLayout.AddView(table); //add your tablelayout to your mainlayout

int number = 19;

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this); //create a new tablerow
    row.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center); //set it to be center (you can remove this if you don't want the row to be in the center)
    TextView column1 = new TextView(this); //create a new textview for left column
    TextView column2 = new TextView(this); //create a new textview for right column

    if (number % 2 == 0) //if your number is even
    {
        column1.Text = "Details " + ++i; //insert text in the first textview
        column2.Text = "Details " + (i + 1); //insert text in the second textview
        row.AddView(column1); //add the first textview to your tablerow (left column)
        row.AddView(column2); //add the second textview to your tablerow (right column)
        table.AddView(row); //add the tablerow to your tablelayout
    }

    else //if your number is odd
    {
        column1.Text = "Details " + ++i;
        row.AddView(column1);

        if (i != number) //if it is not the last item, add another (right) column
        {
            column2.Text = "Details " + (i + 1);
            row.AddView(column2);
        }

        table.AddView(row);
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert in Xamarin.android but I hope this answer your question. Have a nice day.

Regards,
AziziAziz